# Why SQL Sink TableName = "DefaultTableName" and not the value supplied in the parameter

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I am moving data from the Dataverse/Data Lake into an Azure SQL Server.  I have a parameter defined for the TableName.

The Source uses the parameter to read data from the required table, but not the Sink.

Here my parameters are defined and are being passed down from the Pipeline.
[image: Parameters defined]

This is the Sink
[image: Sink]

[image: Sink Settings]

And the Sink Settings using the Dataset Parameter

[image: Sink Dataset]

[image: Sink Dataset paramters]

I get a table created called [landing].[DefaultTableName] no matter what I set as my TableName parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is a working example,**

### DataFlow with dynamic SQL sink:

[image]

[image]

### Parameterized table name in sink Dataset:

[image]

[image]

### Pipeline Setup and new parameter value input:

[image]

### Execute:

[image]

[image]

---

## Conclusions:

What you are trying to do is pass the Dataflow parameter value to Sink dataset parameter, which is not possible. You can only input values to Dataflow parameters from pipeline and not the other way around. And you cannot refer to DataFlow parameter in Dataset cause all are created in different scopes.

**DataFlow Parameter:**

[image]

[image]